# Ionic platforms update returns an error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I just update to ionic beta usin the command lin `npm install -g ionic@beta`

whenever i run `ionic platforms update ios/android`
I got this error:

```
[ERROR] Unknown plugin: @ionic/cli-plugin-.
```

Comment: I believe a stable version of Ionic is out since a long time.. Why do you still install the beta version bro..? Is it a specific requirement..?

Comment: haha Hi Raja Thanks for answering this issue. For one reason Dear Raja :) cordova plugin for salesforce Mobile SDK doesn't support the ionic 2.2.2 I already installed

Answer (score 0):

If you run `ionic info` what version of the ionic CLI are you running it looks like you have updated to V3.

If so then you need to update your command to be:

```
ionic cordova:platform update android
```

More info about CLI changes here - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/blob/v3/docs/cordova-platform.md